# Two column layout like google plus

Tags: css

today i try to re-implement the same two columns layout like google plus post history.

I tried to use column-count, but the divs print one behind the other in the left column first, and then (when the first filled) on the right column.
The divs, in this case, fill correctly the space between them, but in the wrong order.

Then I try to use bootstrap or pure css, with responsive grid design, but I obtain empty space between divs in the same column (just only one div have more height than the nearest).

I need to implement the same system created on google plus :(
Thanks for any future suggestions, have a nice day.

```
.multicols {
    padding:0;
    column-width: 50%;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-width:50%;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-width:50%;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -ms-column-width:50%;
    -ms-column-count: 2;
    -o-column-width:50%;
    -o-column-count: 2;

    column-gap: 0;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 0;
    -ms-column-gap: 0;
    -o-column-gap: 0;
    vertical-align:text-top;
}

.multicols .amulticol {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0;
    min-height: 100px;
    break-inside: avoid;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -ms-column-break-before: avoid;
    -o-column-break-before: avoid;
}
```

Here the code that doesn't work: [jsfiddle.net/PsL8H](http://jsfiddle.net/PsL8H)

Comment: Use [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)  to post your attempted code to and update your question with the link

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PsL8H/ sorry guys.. thanks for patience i'm a bit nervous about this XD

Answer (score 2):

I see that you tried bootstrap and pure css to do this, but I believe you'll need Javascript.

See [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), a "cascading grid layout library" if it's what you need.